# Is there a limit on the amount of categories for an Objective-C Class?

Tags: objective-c, class, objective-c-category

Is there a limit on the amount of categories for an Objective-C Class? I am making a bunch to make my class less lengthy and was just wondering if there was a limit on the amount of them you could have. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, no. But if you're making so many that you're worried about hitting some theoretical limit, you're probably making too many.

Comment: I suspect that performance will bog down before you hit any hard limit.

Comment: @Gavin Good point, is there a good way to go about planning how many are needed? I have 9 methods in this class, and the reason I'm separating them is because I need to make the if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM () .. statements for ipad compatibility for 6/9 of these, so I was thinking of making a category per method? What do you think.

Comment: A category per method seems like a bad idea. I don't think you need to worry about your class being too big if you're talking about 9 methods.

Comment: Hmm @Gavin, would you just include the if statements and add separate code in the same class? or is there a different way to go about doing this. Right now I have the iPad and iPhone storyboards connected to the same .h and .m files, but is there a way I could make a new class for the iPad stuff, then somehow tell the app to choose one of them at startUp?

Comment: Short answer: No, you can't programmatically choose category methods at runtime. Long answer: Yes, you could use method swizzling. Or you could just call a set of methods which do the check and call the appropriate category method, where you would prefix the category methods so that they don't have the same names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit. They are an effective way of keeping long codes clean. Make sure to name them appropriately to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not such a limit. Just try to prefix your Categories to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been answered, no, there is no such limit, at least not that anyone here is aware of. There might be some theoretical limit, but it's unlikely that you would encounter it.

I felt I should post an answer to better answer what you asked in the comments. You wanted to know about how best to go about having different implementations for iPhone and iPad for your methods, and there are a few different options:

- You could simply have if statements in each method that executes the appropriate code depending on whether it is iPhone or iPad.
- You could have separate methods suffixed with "_iphone" or "_ipad", and then from the main methods you could call the appropriate one based on an if statement.
- You could have separate methods suffixed with "_iphone" or "_ipad", and then use method swizzling to replace the implementations of the main methods with the appropriate ones at app launch. This would reduce the overhead of the if statements every time you call a method.

If performance is critical, the last option would have the best performance, if you were calling it many many times. However the last option also requires digging into the Objective-C runtime. The first and second options both involve checking which device it is every single time a method is called. However, if performance isn't super important, the first option is easiest to set up. Also the first option would allow you to have some code in common between the two without duplicating it in separate methods, so it might be ideal if this is the case. Also many times it is nice to be able to look in one place to find all of the logic for handling a particular action, and would make things easiest if somebody else needed to maintain your code.

Comment: Way to go above and beyond. Thanks alot for all the help @Gavin